# Python: Two FOR loops, first doesn't continue

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import webbrowser 

for i in range (1, 3):
   print('loop i ', i)
   for j in range (1, 4):
      webbrowser.open(url)
      print('loop j ', j)
```

The output of this is:

```
loop i 1
loop j 1
loop j 2
loop j 3
```

and then it stops, I can't figure it out why it doesn't come back to the first loop and continue it.

As you can see in the print output, the url is opened in the same way. 3 times then it stops.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you comment out the webbrowser.open(url) command? Do you still get the same output?

Comment: No, when I comment the webbrowser it works, goes in both for loops all the way

Comment: This code works for me, it successfully opens 6 tabs. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It looks like it should work perfectly fine... try removing code about the webbrowser to see if somehow that affects it...

Comment: @Alex could be one of the reasons that I'm using Win 10? I don't think so though. And python 3.7.0

Comment: @Anevo that could be the reason, try some other tests like opening different urls

Comment: @user if I comment webbrowser the code works.. but not with webbrowser.

Comment: @Alex I tried.. it's the same output

Comment: @Anevo That's weird, I'm not sure why that module is doing that... couldn't you just loop the code 12 times instead of 4x3? I don't see a reason for nested for loops.

Comment: or try using `webbrowser.open(url, new=2)`. That should open the url in a new tab (instead of replacing the current url).

Comment: @user the reason why I wanted it like this is because my laptop is not pleased if I open too many tabs, and I was thinking of something like:
First open 4 tabs -> close browser -> open 4 tabs again -> and so on.

Comment: @Anevo ah. I think I have an alternate solution that can work for you... I'll post it in just a minute

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you! that worked! I wonder why though because I tried with webbrowser.open_new(url) and I had the same output as before but with your code it worked.

Comment: @user Thank you, I will wait for your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based off of this response from OP...

> @user the reason why I wanted it like this is because my laptop is not pleased if I open too many tabs, and I was thinking of something like: First open 4 tabs -> close browser -> open 4 tabs again -> and so on. –

```
import webbrowser 
import time

for i in range (1, 12):
   webbrowser.open(url)
   print('loop i ', i)
   if i%4 == 3:
      time.sleep(1)
```

This simply gives the computer a break of 1 second every 4th tab, if it needs it.

Comment: `time.sleep(1)`? `j`? 

Comment: @TrebuchetMS ah sorry, typo for the j, forgot the way i imported time. Thanks

Comment: @user I tried the code, the output is good, goes all the way but the webbrowser only opens the first 4 tabs. After the pause it doesn't open more but it continues the loop ( tried it on Chrome and IE ). Without the `if i%4 == 3 ` & `time.sleep(1)` opens all tabs..

Comment: @Anevo That's strange. Is it a problem if you don't have a pause, or should it be fine? If there's an error with opening after a pause, that's more of an application system error that you should look at than an error with python.

Comment: @user Indeed is strange, No it's not a problem if there's no break, the reason is that after many tabs the laptop starts working slower and it's not efficient.
Alright, I'm going to look deeper into it. 
Thanks a lot for your time, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @Anevo You're welcome! I'd recommend https://superuser.com/ as a good Stack Exchange site to post about this problem if it may be related to hardware. If you think my answer is satisfactory I'd also appreciate you accept my answer :)